Inserting uuid data in a uuid field gives out an error
When i try to create an object inserting uuid data in a uuid field it gives out an error
what is the error that i could not find out in my code and what could be the solution to solve the error when uuid field is not accepting uuid data
    def create(self, validated_data):
        products_data = validated_data.pop('products')
        kitchen_order = KitchenOrder.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for product_data in products_data:
            modifiers_data = product_data.pop('modifiers', [])
            print(f"product id: {product_data}")
            kitchen_order_item = KitchenOrderItem.objects.create(
                kitchen_order=kitchen_order,
                product_id=product_data.get('product_id'),
                quantity=product_data['quantity'],
                note=product_data['note']
            )
            for modifier_data in modifiers_data:
                KitchenOrderItem.objects.create(
                    kitchen_order=kitchen_order,
                    modifier=kitchen_order_item,
                    product_id=modifier_data.get('product_id'),
                    quantity=modifier_data['quantity'],
                    note=modifier_data['note']
                )
        return kitchen_order

"products": [
            {
                "product_id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
                "quantity": 2,
                "note": "safs",
                "modifiers": [
                    {
                        "product_id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
                        "quantity": 2,
                        "note": "safs"
                     }
                ]

            }
        ]

Inserting above error gives out an error like
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/home/suraj/Desktop/backend-third-party-integration/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1067, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
  File "/home/suraj/Desktop/backend-third-party-integration/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1108, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/home/suraj/Desktop/backend-third-party-integration/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/suraj/Desktop/backend-third-party-integration/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1845, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/home/suraj/Desktop/backend-third-party-integration/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1823, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/suraj/Desktop/backend-third-party-integration/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 122, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/suraj/Desktop/backend-third-party-integration/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "/home/suraj/Desktop/backend-third-party-integration/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 92, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/suraj/Desktop/backend-third-party-integration/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/home/suraj/Desktop/backend-third-party-integration/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/suraj/Desktop/backend-third-party-integration/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 105, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "product_id" is of type uuid but expression is of type numeric
LINE 1: ...cf23-b45b-4242-a5a2-ae1d756fa81b'::uuid, 2.00, 0, 8461560438...
                                                             ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.



can you add KitchenOrderItem model ?
